# Gradients and Directional Derivatives

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have this function describing temperature $$T(x,y) = x^2 - 2y^2 $$
It's basically an assignment with 5 sub-part in it. The last part, part e) is a question about an ant crawling along the curve to. It goes:

"An ant is crawling along the curve through (2,1) Should the ant move to experience maximum amount of cooling?"

I have the correct answer in the student solution manual, which makes no sense to me.

The solution manual says:

"To continue to experience maximum rate of cooling the ant should crawl along the curve $$ x = x(t), y =y(t) $$

,which is everywhere tangent to $$ \nabla T(x,y). $$
thus we want $$ \frac{dx}{dt}i + \frac{dy}{dt}j = \lambda(2xi - 4yi)$$
Thus $$ \frac{1}{y}\frac{dy}{dt} = -\frac{2}{x}\frac{dx}{dt}$$
From which we obtain, on integration $$ln|y(t)| = -2ln|x(t)|+ln|C| $$
or $yx^2 = C$. Since the curve passes through $(2, -1)$, we have $yx^2 = -4$. Thus the ant should crawl along the path $ y = -4/x^2$"

Now i don't know how that answer is obtained nor the reason behind the method. Would someone explain both, why we had to integrate that function, and how that function

$$ \frac{dx}{dt}i + \frac{dy}{dt}j = \lambda(2xi - 4yi) $$
Where did the i and j values come from and how did it become this:

$$ \frac{1}{y}\frac{dy}{dt} = -\frac{2}{x}\frac{dx}{dt}$$

That we had to integrate, and why did we need to integrate?

Comment: $i$ and $j$ are horizontal and vertical unit vectors, so $i=(1,0)$, $j=(0,1)$. You can then equate $i,j$ components and express $\lambda$ in terms of $x,y$ and their derivatives, then you get your differential equation. That pretty much explains all, does it not? Also, integration is required to solve the differential equation you got, to give implicit equation representing the curve which ant should follow to experience maximum cooling ( I hope you understand why this resulting curve gives maximum cooling, though)

Answer (score 1):

Note that you must not confuse the temperature $T$ with $t$ the parameter that tells us where on the curve we are.

$\nabla T$ is a vector that describes the direction of the rate of change of $T$.

By definition, $\nabla T = \frac {\partial T} {\partial x}i +\frac {\partial T} {\partial y}j$

$\frac {\partial T} {\partial x} = \frac {\partial (x^2+2y^2} {\partial x} = 2x$

$\frac {\partial T} {\partial y} = \frac {\partial (x^2+2y^2} {\partial y}= 4y$

$\nabla T= 2xi+4yj$

The ant has position vector $xi +yj$ and direction vector $\frac {dx}{dt}i + \frac {dy}{dt}j$.

For this direction vector to be parallel to $\nabla T$ we require $\frac {dx}{dt}i + \frac {dy}{dt}j= \lambda (2xi +4yj)$

Comparing coefficients of $i$ gives $\frac {dx} {dt}=\lambda 2x$.

Make $\lambda$ the subject: $\lambda = \frac 1 {2x} \frac {dx}{dt}$.

Comparing coefficients of $j$ gives $\frac {dy} {dt}=\lambda 4y$.

Make $\lambda$ the subject: $\lambda = \frac 1 {4y} \frac {dy}{dt}$.

Now equate the two parts. $ \frac 1 {2x} \frac {dx}{dt} = \frac 1 {4y} \frac {dy}{dt}$.

They have simplified this as $\frac 1 {y} \frac {dy}{dt} = \frac 2 x \frac {dx}{dt}$.

Comment: How would you go about solving this problem?

Comment: I'm trying to explain the solution you have already been given.

Comment: Yes, that explanation makes sense. Was a bit of yesterday